# Remove the "silenced", "4G", "Battery symbol" and "AM/PM" from notification bar

Tags: htc-one-m8

I want to modify my notification bar so it's more something like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

I'm using a rooted 4.4.2 M8 on Verizon.

Answer (score 3):

Since rooted,  download the Xposed Framework installer from the XDA forums:

*http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053*

Download link is in the first post in the thread:

*http://dl.xposed.info/latest.apk*

---

After Xposed is installed, open the app and install the framework, then soft reboot.

Open the app again, go to downloads section and scroll through the available modules.  There are a few that will do the things that you want.

**UPDATE:** Researching further, I found out that the ***Sense Toolbox*** module will hide status (some people call it the notification) bar icons.[image: sense toolbox]

- [Sense Toolbox homepage](http://sensetoolbox.com/6/modslist)
- [Sense Toolbox download page](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.sensetoolbox.six)

Install the modules you want, enable them on the modules tab in the Xposed app, then reboot.

*Read the thread and links thoroughly. Understand what this will do to your phone. Always do a backup first.*

Comment: "Always do a backup first."  I'm just leaving this here to second that. You REALLY need to make backups. There's a LOT of issues people have that could so easily be solved if you made a full backup! +1 for the answer Xposed is AWESOME.

Comment: @RossC THANKS!! Yes there are way too many people not making backups. Borking androids up seems to be the new norm. We (read as general public) need to read and/or fully read information, so there is an understanding of what we are doing when we make changes. An informed Android user is a smart Android user.

Comment: I learned the hard way by wrecking an expensive device!!

Comment: @RossC Ouch!!....but you learned your lesson. I bet backups are almost a routine now.

Comment: That's just an APK that lets you add in other modules. I looked through the modules and I didn't see anything about removing specific icons from the notification bar. The closest I got was one that let you change the batter icon, you couldn't even remove it.

Comment: Read through the modules better,  I know there is at least one. Read the the descriptions also,  not just the titles.

Comment: @Chipperyman Did you try [GravityBox](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) module?

Comment: @Firelord does that work for HTC 1m8? I use the G2 and G3 Tweakbox modules on my LG Volt, you can disabe or change all of the status bar icons with either of those.